# aiohttp making too many get calls

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a loop to create `tasks` that calls to an endpoint via aiohttp client session.

This works when it does small loads of 10-15 calls to the api. But I will be making approximately 8000+- api calls. Because its going to be 8000 calls, I want to limit my call requests.

```
from aiohttp import ClientSession, TCPConnector
from asyncio import create_task, get_event_loop

# event loops and all have already been created way above. 

tasks = [api_call("endpoint")]  # Another function create and structure all the api tasks here via create_task()

for coro in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
    result = await coro
    ## do other stuffs with result

async def api_call(endpoint):

    requests_headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br"}

    connector = TCPConnector(limit=20, limit_per_host=20)
    async with ClientSession(headers=requests_headers, connector=connector) as session:
        try:
            async with session.get(endpoint) as response:
                assert response.status == 200
                result = await response.json()
        except Exception as e:
           self.logger.error(f"Error retrieving data: {e}")
            result = None
```

What i'm observing is that all 8000 requests are being sent in an instance, and after 1 second, i'm receiving error messages `Cannot connect to host api.example.com:443 ssl:default [Too many open files]`

Any ideas how I can limit my get requests with aiohttp?

Comment: If you are calling `api_call` per request you will create a new connector and session per call. You have to do all calls in **one** session to have rate limiting.

Comment: ah okay. this makes sense! i'll have to restructure it then

Comment: This is also recommended in the docs: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#client-session

_Unless you are connecting to a large, unknown number of different servers over the lifetime of your application, it is suggested you use a single session for the lifetime of your application to benefit from connection pooling._

I made the same mistake and recreated the session with every call